# Converting string to function

Tags: c#, string, function

I want to build in my application the possibility of drawing mathematical functions. In the plotting library that I'm using (OxyPlot) there is a great support for that. See this example:

```
y = ax³ + bx² + cx + d = 0
```

is being plotted this way:

```
new FunctionSeries( x => a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d, /* other stuff, spacing, number of points, etc */ )
```

Trigonometrical functions are done the same way:

```
   y = sin(3x) + 5cos(x)
```

is

```
   new FunctionSeries(x => Math.Sin(3*x) + 5*Math.Cos(x) , ....);
```

I would be very happy if someone could guide me in the conversion between a **string** (written in a textbox for example) and a call of a **method** that has inside the syntax shown.

EDIT: the first parameter in the `FunctionSeries(a, ....)`  `a` is `Func<double, double>`

EDIT2: Is there a way to say to the compiler, hey, believe me `"x => 5*x*x"` is a Func, take it literally

something like :

```
Func<double, double> f = (Func<double, double>)myString;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net/392355#392355](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net/392355#392355)

Comment: For something this simple.. NCalc is a good option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll go with NCalc, if it's not too much asking Simon, could you provide me the simplest example in the world as I couldn't find my necessities in the brief documentation of NCalc. In the examples they are simply calculating the result of a expression parsed from a string. I was looking to transform the string to a Func. Do you think is that possible with NCalc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a partial solution:

```
        var expresionData = new List<DataPoint>();
        Regex pattern = new Regex("[x]");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string a = pattern.Replace(ExpresionString, i.ToString());
            NCalc.Expression exp = new NCalc.Expression(a);
            expresionData.Add(new DataPoint(i,Double.Parse(exp.Evaluate().ToString())));
        }
```

I'm doing a little trick here: I transform each 'x' in the typed string to i, then I evaluate the expression and add the point. It's pretty slow. I'm still very interested in the original question:

**How to transform a string to `Func<double, double`>** (or just make the compiler take it literally).