# Linq Dynamic ParseLambda not resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to use the sample code I found here for something i'm working on:
[How to convert a String to its equivalent LINQ Expression Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree)

In the solution the author uses the following:

```
var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, exp);
```

However, whenever I try to use it, it does not resolve.  I get an error:

> System.Linq.Expressions.DynamicExpression' does not contain a definition for 'ParseLambda'

I installed the System Linq Dynamic nuget package in the project, I've also added a using statement:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

However, that appears greyed out so i'm guessing it's not picking up that the DynamicExpression object i'm referring to is from there, it's picking it up from System.Linq.Expression instead.  Is there a way to fix this?  I've tried making it

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, tagCondition);
```

but still no good, same error and the using statement is still greyed out.

Comment: `System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(...)`?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet using that i get an Error 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this I ended up grabbing the Dynamic.cs file from here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
I added that to my solution and used it, in this one the DynamicExpression class was public so i was found.

Answer (score 10):

The assemblies

```
System.Linq.Dynamic;
System.Linq.Expressions;
```

both contain `DynamicExpression`. Since you need both of these, you will need to either give an alias to `System.Linq.Dynamic` or explicitly as `System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression`

You need to make sure you install System.Linq.Dynamic using the package manager.

A full minimally working example is here:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using myAlias = System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var expression = @"(Foo.Bar == ""barbar"")";
            var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "Foo");
            var e = myAlias.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);

            var test1 = new Foo()
            {
                Bar = "notbarbar",

            };

            var test2 = new Foo()
            {
                Bar = "barbar"
            };

            // false
            var result1 = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(test1);

            // true
            var result2 = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(test2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i do something like using myAlias = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression;   I get an error 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: using myAlias = System.Linq.Dynamic;

Comment: and use it like : myAlias.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, exp);

Comment: same error : Error 1 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' is inaccessible due to its protection level