# How to Convert Predicate to String and String To Predicate

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

I work on a special project that have to convert Predicates (or Expressions) to string and store on the database and retrieve it and convert it to Predicates  and evaluate it because I want to change it in run-time. Please help me to imeplement ConvertStringToPredicate and ConvertStringToPredicate methods.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string predicateStr = GetPredicateFromDb(100);

        Predicate<Account> predicate = ConvertStringToPredicate(predicateStr);

        Account account = new Account();

        var status = account.Evaluate(predicate);

        //...
    }

    public static string GetPredicateFromDb(int id)
    {
        //Get Predicate String From Database
        //...
    }

    public static Predicate<Account> ConvertStringToPredicate(string predicate)
    {
        //???
    }

    public static string ConvertStringToPredicate(Predicate<Account> predicate)
    {
        //???
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public bool Evaluate(Predicate<Account> matchingCriteria)
    {
        //Evaluate Predicate
        //...
    }  
}
```

Comment: This looks like the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Why are you saving a predicate as a string in your database?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because I want to change it in run-time

Comment: And why does that mean you need to persist it to the database? In what format is it stored?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want to save it in database as string(nvarchar) format and retrieve it in a another program and change it in run-time.

Comment: Check this question. It might offer insight on how to solve yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries for expression trees serialization:

1. [metalinq](http://metalinq.codeplex.com/)
2. [expression tree serializer](http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/)
3. [serialize linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq)