# LINQ Select Dynamic Columns and Values

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

For various reasons I need to be able to allow the user to select an item from a database based on their choice of columns and values. For instance, if I have a table:

```
Name   | Specialty       | Rank
-------+-----------------+-----
John   | Basket Weaving  | 12
Sally  | Basket Weaving  | 6
Smith  | Fencing         | 12
```

The user may request a 1, 2, or more columns and the columns that they request may be different. For example, the user may request entries where `Specialty == Basket Weaving` and `Rank == 12. What I do currently is gather the user's request and create a list of`KeyValuePair`where the`Key`is the column name and the`Value` is the desired value of the column:

```
class UserSearch
{
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, string> criteria = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    public void AddTerm(string column, string value)
    {
        criteria.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(column, value);
    }

    public void Search()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // Search for entries where the column's (key's) value matches
            // the KVP's value.
            var query = db.MyTable.Where(???);
        }
    }
}

/* ... Somewhere else in code, user adds terms to their search 
 * effectively performing the following ... */
UserSearch search = new UserSearch();
search.Add("Specialty", "Basket Weaving");
search.Add("Rank", "12");
```

Using this list of `KeyValuePair`'s, how can I most succinctly select database items which match all the criteria?

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext)
{
    // Where each column name (key) in criteria matches 
    // the corresponding value in criteria.
    var query = db.MyTable.Where(???);
}
```

EDIT: I would like to use EntityFramework instead of raw SQL if I can help it.

**UPDATE 3**: I am getting closer. I have discovered a way to use LINQ once I've downloaded
all the values from the table. This is obviously not super ideal because it downloads
everything in the table. So I guess the last step would be to figure out a way where 
I don't have to download the whole table every time. Here is an explanation of what I am doing:

For every row in the table

```
db.MyTable.ToList().Where(e => ...
```

I make a list of bools representing if the column matches the criteria.

```
criteria.Select(c => e.GetType()?.GetProperty(c.Key)?.GetValue(e)?.ToString() == c.Value)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         Basically just gets the value of specific column
                                            by string
```

Then I check to see if this bool list is all true

```
.All(c => c == true)
```

An example of the full code is below:

```
// This class was generated from the ADO.NET Entity Data Model template 
// from the database. I have stripped the excess stuff from it leaving 
// only the properties.
public class MyTableEntry
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Specialty { get; }
    public string Rank { get; }
}

class UserSearch
{
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, string> criteria = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    public void AddTerm(string column, string value)
    {
        criteria.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(column, value);
    }

    public async Task<List<MyTableEntry>> Search()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entries = await db.MyTable.ToListAsync();
            var matches = entries.Where(e => criteria.Select(c => e.GetType()
                                                                  ?.GetProperty(c.Key)
                                                                  ?.GetValue(e)
                                                                  ?.ToString() == c.Value)
                                                      .All(c => c == true));

            return matches.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as if my problem lies with this segment of code:

```
e.GetType()?.GetProperty(c.Key)?.GetValue(e)?.ToString()
```

I am unfamiliar with Expression trees so perhaps the answer lies in them. I may also try Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: I think this post will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree

Your going to have to convert your string that you want in the Where to a actually expression that will work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the generated SQL from the linq to alleviate concerns that you're making unnecessary comparisons in SQL.

Comment: have u solved it yet?

Answer (score 11):

Since your columns and filters are dynamic, **Dynamic LINQ** library may help you here

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Doc: http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic; //Import the Dynamic LINQ library

//The standard way, which requires compile-time knowledge
//of the data model
var result = myQuery
    .Where(x => x.Field1 == "SomeValue")
    .Select(x => new { x.Field1, x.Field2 });

//The Dynamic LINQ way, which lets you do the same thing
//without knowing the data model before hand
var result = myQuery
    .Where("Field1=\"SomeValue\"")
    .Select("new (Field1, Field2)");
```

Another solution is to use **[Eval Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)** which lets you evaluate dynamically c# code at runtime.

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var query = ctx.Entity_Basics;

    var list = Eval.Execute(@"
q.Where(x => x.ColumnInt < 10)
 .Select(x => new { x.ID, x.ColumnInt })
 .ToList();", new { q = query });
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

**Edit** : Answer comment

Be careful, the parameter value type must be compatible with the property type. By example, if the “Rank” property is an INT, only type compatible with INT will work (not string).

Obviously, you will need to refactor this method to make it more suitable for your application. But as you can see, you can easily use even async method from Entity Framework.

If you customize the select also (the return type) you may need to either get the async result  using reflection or use ExecuteAsync instead with ToList().

```
public async Task<List<Entity_Basic>> DynamicWhereAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Register async extension method from entity framework (this should be done in the global.asax or STAThread method
    // Only Enumerable && Queryable extension methods exists by default
    EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterExtensionMethod(typeof(QueryableExtensions));

    // GET your criteria
    var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();
    tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, object>("Specialty", "Basket Weaving"));
    tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, object>("Rank", "12"));

    // BUILD your where clause
    var where = string.Join(" && ", tuples.Select(tuple => string.Concat("x.", tuple.Item1, " > p", tuple.Item1)));

    // BUILD your parameters
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    tuples.ForEach(x => parameters.Add("p" + x.Item1, x.Item2));

    using (var ctx = new TestContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.Entity_Basics;

        // ADD the current query && cancellationToken as parameter
        parameters.Add("q", query);
        parameters.Add("token", cancellationToken);

        // GET the task
        var task = (Task<List<Entity_Basic>>)Eval.Execute("q.Where(x => " + where + ").ToListAsync(token)", parameters);

        // AWAIT the task
        var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The query may look like this `await db.MyTable.Where("Specialty=="Basket Weaving" && Rank=="12"").ToListAsync()`

Comment: Pls update the documentation of `Where` expression in your project. Thanks for the library

Comment: Your library is great! Thanks for writing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a general pattern for dynamic where clauses:

```
//example lists, a solution for populating will follow
List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "Adam", "Joe", "Bob" };
//these two deliberately left blank for demonstration purposes
List<string> Specialties = new List<string> () { };
List<string> Ranks = new List<string> () { };
using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var list = dbContext.MyTable
                        .Where(x => (!Names.Any() || Names.Contains(x.Name)) &&
                                    (!Specialties.Any() || Specialties.Contains(x.Specialty)) &&
                                    (!Ranks.Any() || Ranks.Contains(x.Rank))).ToList();

}
```

Making some assumptions about your underlying data, the following is the SQL that is likely to be generated by the LINQ shown above:

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Adam'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'Joe'
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1000) = 'Bob'

SELECT [t0].[Name], [t0].[Specialty], [t0].[Rank]
FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Name] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)
```

To populate these lists within your UserSearch class:

```
foreach(var kvp in criteria)
{
    switch(kvp.Key)
    {
        case "Name": Names.Add(kvp.Value); break;
        case "Specialty": Specialties.Add(kvp.Value); break;
        case "Rank": Ranks.Add(kvp.Value); break;
    }
}
```

If you're concerned with maintainability and that the table's columns are going to change often, then you may want to go back to using raw SQL via the SqlCommand class. That way, you can easily generate dynamic selects and where clauses. You could even query the list of columns on the table to dynamically determine which options are available for selecting/filtering.

Comment: This is closer. Is there any way I can avoid making comparisons on every column and instead compare only the columns I specify dynamically?

Comment: Not with LINQ, no. If your concern is that the code is ugly, then I'm afraid there is very little you can do to get around that. If your concern is that you're executing unnecessary comparisons, then don't worry about it because the !Names.Any() part of each condition will basically ignore your filter as long as you have no filters in Names. No additional SQL will be generated for the Specialties and Ranks lists in my example.

Comment: My concern is maintainability. It's just more things that must be changed if the table's columns change.

Comment: Then you may not want Entity Framework. I'd recommend in your case if table column changes are likely to just use the good 'ol vanilla SqlCommand class. I will update my answer to reflect this observation.

Answer (score 1):

Fine. Let me give my two cents. If you want to use dynamic LINQ, expression trees should be your option. You can generate LINQ statements as dynamic as you want. Something like following should do the magic.

```
// inside a generic class.
public static IQueryable<T> GetWhere(string criteria1, string criteria2, string criteria3, string criteria4)
{
    var t = MyExpressions<T>.DynamicWhereExp(criteria1, criteria2, criteria3, criteria4);
    return db.Set<T>().Where(t);
}
```

Now in another generic class you can define your expressions as.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> DynamicWhereExp(string criteria1, string criteria2, string criteria3, string criteria4)
{
    ParameterExpression Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    Expression exp1 = WhereExp1(criteria1, criteria2, Param);
    Expression exp2 = WhereExp1(criteria3, criteria4, Param);

    var body = Expression.And(exp1, exp2);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, Param);
}

private static Expression WhereExp1(string field, string type, ParameterExpression param) 
{
    Expression aLeft = Expression.Property(param, typeof(T).GetProperty(field));
    Expression aRight = Expression.Constant(type);
    Expression typeCheck = Expression.Equal(aLeft, aRight);
    return typeCheck;   
}
```

Now you can call the methods anywhere as.

```
// get search criterias from user
var obj = new YourClass<YourTableName>();
var result = obj.GetWhere(criteria1, criteria2, criteria3, criteria4);
```

This will give you a powerfully dynamic expression with two conditions with AND operator between them to use in your where extension method of LINQ. Now you can pass your arguments as you want based on your strategy. e.g. in params string[] or in key value pair list... doesn't matter.

You can see that nothing is fixed here.. its completely dynamic and faster than reflection and you an make as many expressions and as many criterias...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after here. But this should give you an Idea.

```
var query = db.Mytable.Where(x=> x.Specialty == criteria[0].Value && c=> c.Rank == criteria[1].Value).ToString();
```

I am not even sure why you even have to use List. As List needs to be iterated. You can just use Key first the First Condition and Value for the last Condition to avoid List of KeyValuePair.

Comment: Perhaps I need to be more clear. The number and name of the columns may vary. I can't hard code the column name like `x.Specialty` and I can't have a fixed number of search terms in the `.Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @Jakotheshadows's answer but not requiring all the extra checks in the EF output when there's nothing to check, this is closer to what we do in house here:

```
// Example lists, a solution for populating will follow
var Names = new List<string> { "Adam", "Joe", "Bob" };
// These two deliberately left blank for demonstration purposes
var specialties = new List<string>();
var ranks = new List<string>();
using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var list = dbContext.MyTable
       .FilterByNames(names)
       .FilterBySpecialties(specialties)
       .FilterByRanks(ranks)
       .Select(...)
       .ToList();
}
```

The Table

```
[Table(...)]
public class MyTable : IMyTable
{
    // ...
}
```

The Filter By Extensions

```
public static class MyTableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterMyTablesByName<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string[] names)
        where TEntity : class, IMyTable
    {
        if (query == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query)); }
        if (!names.Any() || names.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace))
        {
            return query; // Unmodified
        }
        // Modified
        return query.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
    }
    // Replicate per array/filter...
}
```

Also, there are significant performance issues with using Contains(...) or Any(...) inside an EF query. There is a much faster method using Predicate Builders. This is an example with an array of IDs (this requires the LinqKit nuget package):

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByIDs<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query, int[] ids)
    where TEntity : class, IBase
{
    if (ids == null || !ids.Any(x => x > 0 && x != int.MaxValue)) { return query; }
    return query.AsExpandable().Where(BuildIDsPredicate<TEntity>(ids));
}
private static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildIDsPredicate<TEntity>(
    IEnumerable<int> ids)
    where TEntity : class, IBase
{
    return ids.Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.New<TEntity>(false),
        (c, id) => c.Or(p => p.ID == id));
}
```

This outputs the "IN" syntax for a query which is really fast:

```
WHERE ID IN [1,2,3,4,5]
```