# C# - Evaluate if statements in a string

Tags: c#

So, i'm very new to C#, and i'm trying to evaluate if statements in a string.
Here's an example:

```
string toEval = "5 > 4";
```

I want this to return true if 5 is bigger than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your inverted commas. You possibly need to include a .ToString() if you want it in string form `string toEval = (5 > 4).ToString()` however if the value is what you are after then you probably want `bool toEval = 5 > 4;`

Comment: No worries... No sure why I'm getting so many down-votes for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `>` is a predefined arithmetic operator for comparing two numeric values you cannot applied it on string values. To complete your requirement you can implement the scenario like this:

Let `a` and `b` are two string variables of integer type and are initialized with `5` and `4` respectively. `toEval` be the output variable.

```
 int a = 5, b = 4;
 string toEval = "";
 if (a > b)
    toEval = "A is bigger than B";
 else
    toEval = "B is bigger than A";
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OwxKcY)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Expression` class in .NET, which is pretty exciting, but sadly, there is no built-in `Expression` parser.

But you still can evaluate simple math expresions this way:

```
 var evaluator = new DataTable();
 string toEval = "5 > 4";
 bool result = (bool)evaluator.Compute(toEval, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this fully you could use the System.Linq.Dynamic library as discussed in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree) There's other libraries mentioned there too.