# Dynamic LINQ - select certain fields from ICollection Field

Tags: c#, lambda, dynamic-linq

I have table like this:

```
class x
{
public int Id {set;get;}
public ICollection<y> items {set;get;}
}
class y
{
public int Id {set;get;}
public string name {set;get;}
public int price {set;get;}
public datetime create_date {set;get;}
public int count {set;get;}
}
```

and I want to query dynamically to get all items y (just name and price fields) that meets the condition x.id > 100

I use [Dynamic-LINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

everything is fine with the where condition, my issue is in select statement, I've tried the following:

```
db.x.where("id>100").select("new (items.select("new {name,price}"))");
```

and

```
db.x.where("id>100").select("new (items.select("name,price")");
```

nothing is working!

could you please help me!

I've tried to return all fields, and it's working fine, like this:

```
db.x.where("id>100").select("new (items)");
```

Comment: related : [How to convert a String to its equivalent LINQ Expression Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online example of [Dynamic LINQ - SelectMany](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E76mjd)

You can try using these samples:
`db.x.Where("Id > 100").SelectMany("x => x.items.Select(r => new (r.name, r.price))")`
or
`db.x.Where("Id > 100").SelectMany("items").Select("new (name, price)")`

[Code example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DU3cNP)

Comment: do you know if I can select extra fields from class x, etc.. id ? is selectmany does the work ?

Comment: Try to using  `db.x.Where("Id > 10").SelectMany("x => x.items.Select(r => new (x.Id as ParentId, r.name, r.price))");` to get `x.Id` as `ParentId` in result collection

Answer (score 0):

Try using adding one more select after selecting all the items

```
db.x.where("id>100").select("new (items)").select("new {name,price}");
```

Comment: I tried your solution, unfortunately, is not working,
anyway, I can get fields like this (it's not fit me):

Select("new (items[0].name , items[0].price)")

Coz this way i can get one item each time, I need them all