# How can I convert string to linq lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use string predicate instead of lambda code.

Here is list of dictionary:

```
void GenerateData()
{
    DataDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
    {
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"a","1-1" },
            {"b","1-2" }
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"a","1-3" },
            {"b","1-4" }
        }
    };
}
```

And find "1-1" from "a"

```
var data = DataDictionary.AsQueryable();

var result = data.Where(d => d["a"] == "1-1");
```

Can i convert **d => d["a"] == "1-1"** to string context? like **"d => d[\"a\"] == \"1-1\""**

Finally, I want use like this.

```
ProcessContext("a", "==\"1-1\"")
ProcessContext("a", "!=\"1-1\"")

void ProcessContext(string Field, string Context)
{
    string predicate = $"d => d[\"{Field}\"] {Context}"
    var result = data.Where(predicate);
}
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

**Update**

I tried Orace's link  [How to convert a String to its equivalent LINQ Expression Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-linq-expression-tree)

It looks perfect solution.
But I got an error.
I will try to solve.

```
//Prev - It works
var result1 = data.Where(d => d["a"] == "1-1");

//Use Dynamic linq - 'Syntax error'
var result2 = data.Where("d => d[\"a\"] == \"1-1\"");
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but if `DataDictionary` is a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, why call `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Can you explain why `Func<string, string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>> getResult = (k, v) => DataDictionary.Where(d => d[k] == v);` wouldn't be useful for you?

Comment: How does `void ProcessContext(string Field, string Context)` help you? What problem have you got that this solves?

Comment: I also want `DataDictionary.Where(d => d[k] != v);` I think my post is not cleared. Edit for this

Comment: @YSR - Can you explain why `Func<string, bool, string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>> getResult = (k, b, v) => DataDictionary.Where(d => b ? d[k] == v : d[k] != v);` wouldn't be useful for you?

Comment: I want dynamic context. Like `a==1` `a < 10` `a != "a"` `(a==1) && (b<10)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a String to its equivalent LINQ Expression Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-linq-expression-tree)

Comment: @YSR - Yes, I understand that. But why? Why do you need it? And what problem do you solve with it? How does it surface to the end user?

Comment: @YSR - You have to somehow build these dynamic strings. How are you doing that?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I will provide customizable search funtion from parsed dataset for end user.

Comment: @YSR - So you're presenting the strings `"==\"1-1\""` and `"!=\"1-1\""` (as an example) for the user to select? It seems to me that a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` could give you a more user friendly approach without resorting to dynamic predicates.

Comment: @Enigmativity - User can type any Context string. And Dictionary for what?

Comment: You can create dictionaries of delegates with strings as keys. You present the keys to the users and you execute the delegates without resorting to dynamically generated code.

Comment: @YSR - Are you saying you want the users to type their own queries?

Comment: Yes. They need their own queries.

Comment: @YSR - That doesn't seem at all practical. It seems to me that you could do much better with a simple query builder.

Comment: Isn't it an injection attack vector ? What about if a user enter some malicious expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create string predicate with [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/). Unfortunately, I am not familiar with it enough to tell how to iterate over a nested dictionary, so I use combined approach of a simple predicate `$"Key == @0 && Value == @1"` and `foreach` loop. You might want to learn more about this nuget package to get rid of `foreach` loop.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

namespace DynamicLinqDemo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var item = GetDictionaryItem();
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionaryItem()
        {
            var dict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"a","1-1" },
                    {"b","1-2" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"a","1-3" },
                    {"b","1-4" }
                }
            };

            var Field = "a";
            var Context = "1-1";
            string predicate = $"Key == @0 && Value == @1";

            foreach (var item in dict)
            {
                var result = item.AsQueryable().Where(predicate, Field, Context).ToList();

                if (result.Count > 0)
                    return item;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ProcessContext(string Field, string Context)
{
        Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p1 = d => d.ContainsKey(Field);
                Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p2 = d => d[Field] == Context;
                Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p3 = d => p1(d) && p2(d);
    var result = data.Where(p3);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to explain how this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: we can change the ProcessContext(string Field, string Context) to return func as below:

Comment: Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p1 = d => d.ContainsKey(Field);
            Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p2 = d => d[Field] == "1-1";
            Func<Dictionary<string, string>, bool> p3 = d => p1(d) && p2(d); return p3;

Comment: The OP is trying to say `Context` is `"==\"1-1\""` or `"!=\"1-1\""` - so the context includes the operator and the value. You are assuming that it's only the value and that the operator is fixed as `==`.

Comment: Sorry  I ignored that. Thanks for pointing that out